# Site.com and VF pages in community

Tags: visualforce, community, site.com

I have community implemented with VF pages(10+ pages). Each VF page extends the main VF page(aka template with header, footer element)

Also I need to have several pages(2 pages) to be implemented with site.com

How can I embed site.com page to use VF template in order not to duplicate header, footer on site.com but have common place where heade and footer is managed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the only way to use Visualforce inside of Site.com is with an iFrame so feasibly you could have your header and footer in an iframe although I'm not sure I'd recommend that approach. It would seem that the easiest way is to have two copies of the markup and styling, one for Site.com and one for your Visualforce template.